# 2 активных соединения с сетью

Tags: android, wifi

Необходимо по Wifi передавать команды и получать результат с устройства(которое раздает WIFI).
Одновременно с этим по 4G передавать данные на сервер.

Возможно ли такое?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16260866/13483092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать сеть из близких устройств можно использовать wifi p2p network. Для этого есть даже куча примеров на GitHub и есть Nearby api. Устройства будут передавать команды в формате сервер/клиент. На передачу данных на сервер оно не повлияет.